# Linking multiple classes with each other (Objects)

Tags: java, arrays, object

Basically, I've got to make a text editing software that will have multiple users that can work with the documents created in the application.

The application runs and whoever is controlling the application will introduce the amount of users that he wants to create (as many as the he feels like), and the amount of documents to create as well.

From there, a menu will appear to edit the text and blah blah blah... (I have the menu part done an working).

There will be 6 classes (including Main). `Editor`, `SharedDocs`, `UserDocs`, `Document` and `TempDoc`.

How they work is, the `Main` instance creates an object of the `Editor`, the `Editor` creates two objects, `SharedDocs` and `UserDocs`. And each one of those will create as many objects as necessary from the two remaining (`SharedDocs` will create `Document` AND `UserDocs` will create `TempDoc`).

Each `Document` instance has a name and a number of users that can use it...

I would post a picture but I don't have enough reputation...

My question is how can I link the classes (using arrays or so) in a way that I don't use array in the `Main` and/or `Editor` classes?

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear what you wanna do. Can you elaborate on "link the classes"?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an array?

Comment: You mean how to use `List`, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` or the thread safe counterparts in `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: I can't use arrays ONLY on the classes Main and Editor, the rest I can and I can't because my teacher doesn't want me to... And I think I'm getting it, thank you anyway! ^.^